AWS Cloudfront with an external domain as custom behaviour
I have a domain (example.com) connected to a CloudFront. The setup as follows:

Default Behaviour (*): An origin that is connected to S3 that hosts a NextJS application and is working just fine.

Custom Behaviour (/blogs/*): An origin that is connected to an external domain (blog.example.com) with the path of index.php.


Keeping in mind that blog.example.com is:

Hosting a WordPress Blogs.
The WordPress Address (URL): blog.example.com
The Site Address (URL): example.com/blogs/

The setup works fine when I visit example.com/blogs/, I do see the WordPress blogs.
My problem is when I visit a single blog post like: example.com/blogs/blog-post-slug, I get a 301 redirected to blog.example.com/blogs/blog-post-slug
I have no clue why this could be happening, I tried messing around with Cloudfront functions and .htaccess but to no avail
I'd really appreciate if anyone could help on this issue as I've been struggling on it for days and there's no direct clue on what to do or what the problem could be.
